# Prevent iframe from reloading the parent window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, sandbox

Is it possible to prevent an iframe from reloading the parent window?

The `sandbox` attribute without `allow-top-navigation` prevents redirection but doesn't prevent reloading.

PS: I need the sandbox to allow both `allow-scripts` and `allow-same-origin`.

Comment: I have the same problem here in my web app with BPM integration. Another way to integrate web aplications?

Comment: My college had the same problem with BPM integration too. Seems it's a hard work.

Answer (score 1):

See the findings here, it was a question asked previously. It experiments with stopping the page reload using **preventDefault()**

```
$(window).bind({
    beforeunload: function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    },
    unload: function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Original Answer

[Prevent refreshing / reloading a page with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880974/prevent-refreshing-reloading-a-page-with-javascript)

> Note: This can be done using Javascript also with a bit more work.