# Navigate hook from React Router Dom lets me navigate to desired page when I reload but comes back to same page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, reload

I want user to navigate to Home page of website when user refreshed the page .

I am using React-Router-Dom library to navigate.

I set the paths to true when user navigate to "/textbox" page and append a event listener for detecting page reload but when I reload it actually navigate to homepage but comes back to "/textbox" page right after reloading. IDK why?

here it is teh code:

```
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
const navigate = useNavigate();
const locations = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(paths);
    if (locations.pathname === "/textbox") {
      setPaths(true);
      window.addEventListener("beforeunload", onReload);
    } else {
      console.log("Not reloaded");
    }
    return () => {};
  });

function onReload() {
    if (paths) {
      navigate("/", { replace: true });
    }
}
```

I tried a lot of things to solve to detect reload in react but I guess its related to react-router-dom.

I will be gratefull if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have two issues in here: first `navigate` refers to `react-router-dom` history, and not to browser history  API, second `useEffect`, with no dependency array, is triggered at every render.

Because of the first issue react navigates to "/" in its own history, but, from browser point of view, user is refreshing the `/textbox` page, that's why you see the "/" for one moment (react moves to this path, literally  "before unload") and "/textbox" then (browser accomplished user request to refresh the page with path "/textbox").

I suggest you the following change

```
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

// ...

const navigate = useNavigate();
const locations = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
  // we need to add it just once
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", onReload);
  return () => {
    // let's remove it on component unmount
    window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", onReload);
  };
}, []); // only one time, not at every render

const onReload = event => {
  if (locations.pathname !== "/") {
    // this is the important point
    // you need to prevent the default browser history API event
    event.preventDefault();
    navigate("/", { replace: true });
  }
}
```

Note that to prevent default browser event you may need something like this [Prevent refreshing / reloading a page with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880974/prevent-refreshing-reloading-a-page-with-javascript)

Comment: Still same issue ! When I click reload button it gets to home page for mili sec and comes back to /textbox even after event.preventDefault() function

Comment: Check the link I shared, you may need to add `unload` event listener too. If that ll works I ll update my answer.

Comment: No progress Still the same issue event after adding unload event